# how can i display UITextfields inside of UITableviewcells if user click the "+" Button in UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have one "**+**" button in `UIView`. My requirement is, if i click that button `UITextFields` displayed in `UITableViewCells`. I am having idea how to display the `UITextFields` in `UIView` if user clicks the "**+**" button. But i dont have any idea how to display `UITextFields` inside of `UITableViewCells` if user hits the "**+**" button. Please kindly help me anybody. Yesterday i strucked with this functionality. I tried some code. But it is not worked properly. But i had not found any solution. Thanks in advance.

```
UIButton *myGreenIconButton1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[myGreenIconButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(GreenIconButtonClicked)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [myGreenIconButton1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"index.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

myGreenIconButton1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

myGreenIconButton1.frame = CGRectMake(285, 144, 25, 25);

[self.view addSubview:myGreenIconButton1];


-(void)GreenIconButtonClicked

{

   view=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, 300, 20)];

   text1=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 80, 100, 20)];

   text1.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

   text1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

   text1.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.662745 green:0.662745 blue:0.662745 alpha:0.5];

   text1.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];

   text1.contentVerticalAlignment=UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;

   text1.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;

   text1.delegate=self;

   [view addSubview:text1];

   text2=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 80, 100, 20)];

   text2.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;

   text2.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

   text2.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.662745 green:0.662745 blue:0.662745 alpha:0.5];

   text2.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];

   text2.contentVerticalAlignment=UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;

   text2.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;

   text2.delegate=self;

   [view addSubview:text2];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

   static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

   if (!cell)

   {

      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

   }

     [cell.textLabel setText:@""];

     [view setTag:101];

     NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

     UITableViewCell *cell1 = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:ip];

     UITextField *textField = (UITextField*)[cell1 viewWithTag:101];

     UITextField *textField1=(UITextField*)[cell1 viewWithTag:101];

     UITextField *textField2=(UITextField*)[cell1 viewWithTag:101];

     [cell.contentView addSubview:text1];

     [cell.contentView addSubview:text2];

     [cell.contentView addSubview:text3];

     return cell;

}
```

Comment: Your question needs clarity. Do you need to add cell with a text field when user clicks on '+' button?

Comment: @NagaMalleshMaddali thanks for your response. I need to add textfields insdie of UITableviewcells when user clciks on '+' button

Comment: please help me any body...I am struck this functionality.....please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a example for your requirement and posted it on github. You can find code [Here](https://github.com/NagaMallesh/CustomTableViewCell)

I have created a custom table view cell with text field on it.

Comment: Hi if i can add two more textfileds in cell how to do this.please tell me.i want to add 3 textfileds in cell

Comment: In the example project, you will see a xib file by name "TextFieldCell". In that xib I have place UITableViewCell. You can add two more text fields on that by adjusting their frames.

Comment: i am adding two textfields and giving connection.but in coding part how can i write remaining two textfields. if( !cell )
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TextFieldCell" owner:self options:nil];
        
        cell=textFieldcell;
        
        
    }

Comment: Just give tag in inspector to those textfields. Read the values from text fields like this UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[textFieldcell.contentView viewForTag:1001];

Comment: i am add this line of code in - (UITableViewCell *)textFieldCellForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CELL_IDENTIFIER];
    
    if( !cell )
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TextFieldCell" owner:self options:nil];
        
//        cell=textFieldcell;
        
        UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[textFieldcell.contentView viewForTag:1001];
        
        
    }
    
    return cell;
}
But i got error like "No visible interface for 'UIView' declares the selector 'viewForTag:'"

Comment: sorry for the typo. Its viewWithTag: not viewForTag:

Answer (score 1):

First create custom cell with xib or without and do following manner its working for you :

**CustomCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell {

}
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
@end
```

**CustomCell.m**

```
#import "CustomCell.h"

@implementation CustomCell
@synthesize textField;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        self.textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.textField];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

**Your TableView .h**

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *array;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tblView;
```

**Your Table View .m**

```
@synthesize array;
@synthesize tblView;

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[tblView reloadData];

}

-(int)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if( [array count ] > 0 )
    {
       return 1;  

    }
  return 0;
}


-(int)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 if( [array count ] > 0 )
    {
       return [array Count];  

    }
  return 0;

}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CustomCell%d%d",indexPath.row,indexPath.section];
    [tblCreateProfile registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    cellIdentifier =nil;

    cell.textField.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


return cell;

}

-(void)GreenIconButtonClicked

{

   [array addObject:@"Test"];
   [tblView reloadData];


}
```

Answer (score 0):

So just try in Custom TableViewCells. So that You can Achieve the solution for this problem.

Comment: Just refer here for custom cell :http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Comment: In that add a custom button + and in button click ,create a UITextview for one particular cell.May this will useful i think.